# How can I hide executed commands run from a Makefile script and only show the output?

Tags: bash

I have a Makefile script with a task containing an rsync statement, when I run the script it outputs the actual rsync command and the response from the rsync command. I want to hide the command and only show the response OR if possible style the rsync command. How can this be done?

See the code below, I've managed to style some of it as you can see. (FYI: I've left out a bunch of tasks etc, and yeah I know this is some old school stuff :) )

```
# Load environment variables from .env file
include .env

# Define ANSI colors
GRAY=\033[0;37m
NC=\033[0m

# Define default target
.PHONY: deploy
deploy:
    @echo " Starting deployment."
    rsync -azP --delete --exclude-from=.deployignore --checksum --no-perms  -e "ssh -p $(SSH_PORT)" $(LOCAL_PATH) $(SSH_USER)@$(SSH_HOST):$(REMOTE_PATH) | awk '{print "${GRAY}> " $$0 "${NC}"}'
    @echo "✅ All modified files have been deployed."
```

And of course, I'm running it using `make deploy`.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 but I would very much like this to work on recent Mac OS versions as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: But I would very much like this to work on Mac OS (recent versions) as well if possible.

Comment: Please add how you invoke the script. If the script is called `myscript`, do you type `myscript` in the terminal or  `bash myscript` or something else?

Comment: Ok thanks for the comments! It's a Makefile, I didn't think that would matter but I realise maybe it does. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to run commands "silently" in a makefile.

1. Prefix the particular command with `@`, like: `@rsync -azP ...` (you already did this with the `@echo` commands).
2. Add the special target `.SILENT` to your makefile, like:

   ```
   # Define default target
   .SILENT:
   .PHONY: deploy
   deploy:
   ```
3. Run `make` with the `-s` or `--silent` parameter.

[See here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19504-01/802-5880/make-25/index.html) for more info.

Comment: +1 ... GNU `make` also has `-s, --silent, --quiet` options to quieten globally